# default gateway to set on devices connected to routerless auto-ip LAN?

Tags: ip, lan, gateway

I have a TCP/IP device connected to the ethernet port on my windows 7 laptop.

The laptop has a static IP address but is set to use auto-IP devices on the LAN

The device can be set to use a static IP address, but it requires that a default gateway and subnet mask be set as well. I would like to set this so that both the laptop and device have static IP addresses.

What should these be set to? Or where can I find the info on my laptop that tells me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all communication will happen on between device and laptop, logical way is to put them both in the same subnet so default gateway is actually not important at all. If you need to provide some address for it you can put the address of the other device. Only important thing is for them to be in the same subnet.

So for example the static IP configuration can be:

**Device:**

```
IP:   192.168.10.1
MASK: 255.255.255.0
GW:   192.168.10.2
```

**Laptop:**

```
IP:   192.168.10.2
MASK: 255.255.255.0
GW:   192.168.10.1
```